# Updating a Google App Engine module

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gae-module

When I try to update my Google App Engine module, I get an error saying that the name and version are already in use (which they are, I'm trying to UPDATE). I've tried updating the whole EAR as well as just the module that I want to update, but both result in the same errors:

```
Unable to update:
com.google.appengine.tools.admin.HttpIoException: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?module=stomp&app_id=<my_app_id>&version=stomp&
400 Bad Request
Version 'stomp' is already in use as a module name. Please use a different version.

    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.send1(AbstractServerConnection.java:293)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.send(AbstractServerConnection.java:253)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.post(AbstractServerConnection.java:232)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.send(AppVersionUpload.java:973)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.beginTransaction(AppVersionUpload.java:645)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.doUpload(AppVersionUpload.java:147)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.doUpdate(AppAdminImpl.java:445)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.update(AppAdminImpl.java:55)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg$UpdateAction.execute(AppCfg.java:1339)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.executeAction(AppCfg.java:325)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.<init>(AppCfg.java:211)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.<init>(AppCfg.java:122)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.main(AppCfg.java:118)
com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AdminException: Unable to update app: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?module=stomp&app_id=<my_app_id>&version=stomp&
400 Bad Request
Version 'stomp' is already in use as a module name. Please use a different version.

    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.doUpdate(AppAdminImpl.java:451)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.update(AppAdminImpl.java:55)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg$UpdateAction.execute(AppCfg.java:1339)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.executeAction(AppCfg.java:325)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.<init>(AppCfg.java:211)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.<init>(AppCfg.java:122)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.main(AppCfg.java:118)
Caused by: com.google.appengine.tools.admin.HttpIoException: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?module=stomp&app_id=<my_app_id>&version=stomp&
400 Bad Request
Version 'stomp' is already in use as a module name. Please use a different version.

    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.send1(AbstractServerConnection.java:293)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.send(AbstractServerConnection.java:253)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.post(AbstractServerConnection.java:232)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.send(AppVersionUpload.java:973)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.beginTransaction(AppVersionUpload.java:645)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.doUpload(AppVersionUpload.java:147)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.doUpdate(AppAdminImpl.java:445)
    ... 6 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is complaining that both the module and version share the same name 'stomp', try using different version and module names.

I have not yet found this documented in the App Engine documentation, but it appears to be a restriction that you cannot have a module name the same as its version name, for example a module with this yaml file will not be updatable:

```
application: my-app-id
version: test
module: test
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
```

Although you will be able to run an update, to upload the initial version of your module, when you try to update it a second time it will fail with this error:

```
Error 400: 
--- begin server output ---
Version 'test' is already in use as a module name. Please use a different version.
--- end server output ---
```

Comment: I should mention this also works when converting from the deprecated backends to modules.  You have to delete the old module versions due to the name conflict in order to upload.